# How can I get solution to this partial differential equation using Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Solve: $\frac{\partial ^3z}{\partial x^3}-4\frac{\partial^3z}{\partial x ^2\partial y}+\frac{\partial ^3 z}{\partial x \partial y^2}-2\frac{\partial^3z}{\partial y^3}=e^{2x+y} $

I want to get the solution to this partial differential equation using Wolfram Alpha. I don't know what to put in the search bar.

Comment: Check out this [WolframAlpha hyperlink](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/differential-equations/), @Soumee.

Comment: You can write $\enspace$ D[z[x,y],{x,3}] - 4*D[z[x,y],{x,2},y] + D[z[x,y],x,{y,2}] - 2*D[z[x,y],{y,3}] = e^(2x+y) $\enspace$ but I don't know how to get an answer for this third-order linear partial differential equation by WolframAlpa.

Comment: Are you interested in a general solution or a specific solution? Wolfram might be able to give you a solution if you specify boundary conditions.

Comment: @WinterSoldier Can I get general solution from wolfram alpha?

Comment: @Soumee, unfortunately, I do not know how to get a general solution using the online version of Wolfram Alpha. However, I did get a (ugly) general solution using Maple.